# Flutter: Firestore how to save query results?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page that uses collection from FireStore to display information. I have Card with InkWell that uses onTap to open new page and pass DocumentSnapshot. Now in opened page i want to perform Query of different collection and get data from node where title is equals to passed DocumentSnapshot's title. For this i have written a little code. Now i want to get result's and save it. To be specific i want to save from query nodes 'title','desc' and 'phone' as String to use it.

I used this code to make query but don't know how to save said nodes:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshot(BuildContext context) async* {
yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('campus' + widget.locationTitle.get('type'))
    .where('title', isEqualTo: widget.locationTitle.get('title'))
    .snapshots();
```

}

Comment: instead of `snapshots()` use `get()` method and call `then()` to get your real data you want to save

Comment: Can you show me how its done?

Comment: alternatively (easier solution) you can use `var data = await [your firebase "where" statement].get()`